# Nothing shows when I use select *

Tags: mysql

I created some tables but when I want to check if my data is inside it doesn't show anything when
I use select * from Project it just appears null and I don't have null values I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong it just appears that the foreign key is restrict

```
 `create table Department
(
    `did    integer      not null auto_increment,
    Dname   varchar(50) default 'HR',
    location varchar(50) default 'Chicago',
    primary key(did)`
    
);

`create table Employee`
(
    Eid     integer         not null auto_increment,
    DepartmentID    integer  default 5,
    Ename   varchar(50)     default 'Josh',
    Erank   integer         default 2,
    Salary  real            default 5000.00,
    primary key(Eid),
    foreign key(DepartmentID) references Department(did)
   
);
/*drop table Project;*/
create table Project
(
    Pid integer             not null auto_increment,
    DepartmentID  integer    default 5,
    Pname varchar(50)       default 'Sorting',
    budget  real            default 5000.00,
    StartYear   integer     default 2000,
    primary key(Pid),
    foreign key(DepartmentID) references Department(did)
    
);

insert
into Project(DepartmentID, Pname, budget, StartYear)
values(1, 'OS', 5000.00, 2018),
      (2, 'Net', 6000.00, 2020);
    

select  *
from Project;
```

Comment: did you insert any data into the database?

Comment: Yes i did in the code I update what i entered and appeared Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`assignmet4practice`.`project`, CONSTRAINT `project_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`DepartmentID`) REFERENCES `department` (`did`))

Comment: Maybe you need to issue a `commit;` after the last `create` and after the `insert` statements. The row has not been commited to the database yet when you issue the `select`.

Comment: I tried that and no hopes still apears as foriegn key failed

Comment: Insert rows into the Department table first. Project table refers to Department ID column and none is found. In other words, Department must have rows with ID = 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Add `COMMIT` statements:

```
create table Project...
commit;
insert into Department values('HR','Chicago');
insert into Department values('Admin','New York');
insert into Project...
commit;
select  * from Project;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle.  There are no rows in Department, so the restraint keeps the insert into Projects from happening.  Also, I removed the backticks:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=64f8f0e9cccce2eb2ab77b37fcce54fd